# How to set selection mode as First Object in Forge Viewer Programmatically

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have displayed BIM model in Forge Viewer in our web application. In that the BIM model (Navisworks file) is displayed in the Forge Viewer successfully. But we need to set the Selection Mode as "First Object" in Forge Viewer Settings. We have used Forge Aggregated Viewer.

We have used javascript code for processing. How to programmatically set the Selection mode as "First Object" by using javascript/jquery?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/profiles/), you can create a custom profile (or clone an existing one) and set this profile to the viewer :

```
const customProfileSettings = {
    settings: {
        selectionMode: 1 //enum value, 0 is default 'First Object' is 1
    }
};
const customProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customProfileSettings);

viewer.setProfile(customProfile);
```